# Ember.js action bubbles up and skips a route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

## Setup

Imagine an Ember.js app (tried v1.13.9) with this structure:

1. ApplicationRoute
2. IndexRoute
3. IndexController

On the index template, there's simply a button with an action:

```
<!-- index/template.js -->
<button {{action 'ping' 'index template'}}>index</button>
```

All routes/controllers handle this action, printing out a message and passing the action up until it reaches `ApplicationRoute`. Eg, for `IndexRoute` it is:

```
// excerpt from index/route.js
actions: {
  ping(from) {
    console.log('IndexRoute^ping from', from);
    return true;
  }
}
```

This same action can also originate at `IndexController`:

```
// excerpt from index/controller.js
thingsHappen() {
  this.send('ping', 'index controller');
}
```

You can see the code and play with it at these URLs:

- See the Github gist: https://gist.github.com/pablobm/8fa2b8ae36e875cb9944
- Play with the twiddle: http://ember-twiddle.com/8fa2b8ae36e875cb9944

## Question

When you press the button, the messages show that the action is seen by all three routes/controllers, in order, from the inside bubbling up. However, when the action is sent from `IndexController`, it skips `IndexRoute`. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's related to the fact that the route hasn't truly been transitioned to yet.  So the `index` route isn't part of the current chain.  If you want to make sure the `index` route has been loaded you can hook up to the transition promise and wait for it to complete before calling your action.

```
 setupController(controller, model, transition) {
    controller.wake('non attached');
    transition.then(function(){
      controller.wake('attached');
    });
  },
```

http://ember-twiddle.com/e36c0228967fb4485d27

Comment: D'oh, you are right. This is one other of many things in Ember.js that are not obvious at all :-/

Comment: Well, you _are_ doing non obvious things in your code :P